# Which is better, SQL transaction or Java side transaction for an banking application?

Tags: java, sql, transactions, banking

I am making a banking application and not able to decide which will be a better approach to handle fund transfer transactions. Using SQL may need rewritting code if the database changes. Using pure Java to handle will make it little more complex in terms of locking the accounts for the transactions. What is the best practice for this scenario?
PS - please consider a distributed application server in this case.

Comment: "Better" how? Performance? Maintainability? Reliability?

Comment: Using pure Java: what do you mean by that? Java is not a database. It doesn't persist anything. starting/committing a transaction using JDBC is the same thing as starting/committing a transaction using SQL.

Comment: Mean the transaction in java code - business logic.

Comment: By better I mean transaction integrity - correctness.

Comment: You can't guarantee anything regarding the integrity of the state of your database using "pure Java". The databases are transactional for a good reason. Of course you absolutely need to use SQL transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any application, that leaves the DB in a possibly inconcistent state on hard crash, is unfit for banking use. Applications, that leverage so called "Java Transactions" are part of this group.

Any serious banking application will have all writing processes encapsulated into a server-side capsule (read: stored procedure) and not allow any write access to any table. Read access will be served by a mixture of stored procedures and views.

Together with a crash-resistant RDBMS, this guarantees all-or-nothing handling of jobs.

Answer (score 2):

All participating resources (including your database as well as any other endpoint or middleware) must also join the same transaction. A transaction is nothing that ends at the boundaries of a component, it spans all involved components in the system. Otherwise, it's no transaction.
There should be a driving component, which is usually your own code or some middleware, which starts and commits/rollbacks a transaction. Anyone else joins in. They idea of a transaction is, to reverse the actions of all involved components, if something fails (and to hide already-happened actions to anyone outside the transaction until it is successfully committed).
My answer would be: You need both, database and application level transactions, because a transaction involves all participating components.