# How to make SQL insert safely?

Tags: android, mysql, multithreading, thread-safety

I am creating a Hotel Booking System for the Android application.

I was thinking about how to implement a safe way to insert a booking into my database. The request will be sent from the app to the MySQL database (which is hosted on a web server) via my web service.

When I create a booking I insert the: CustomerID, HotelID, RoomID (via a nested select statement to find an available room), checkInDate and checkOutDate.

However, how can I ensure that two different people won't book the same/last room if they both hit 'book now' at roughly the same time. I thought about using `Synchornised`for the java method but will that make any difference if a range of different users on different mobiles try to make a booking?

Comment: Read about SQL locking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [**transactions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327065/which-is-better-sql-transaction-or-java-side-transaction-for-an-banking-applica).

Using transactions you will be able to isolate access to a given set of records into a single, atomic logical entity. Any operation of a certain complexity affects multiple rows, columns and even tables, or needs multiple (atomic or non-atomic) statements to complete. A transaction is a mechanism to ensure logical consistency of your data even if any of these operations fails. In that case, the incomplete transaction is rolled back, otherwise the transaction is committed.

And these are exactly the both possible outcomes with transactions: `commit` or `rollback`. In pseudo code it looks like this:

```
begin transaction
try {
  required operations to reserve a room for a given time frame

  if( success)
      commit transaction
  else
      rollback transaction

} catch {
  rollback transaction
}
```

Synchronizing in Java is certainly possible, but it has several major drawbacks:

- it prevents you from scaling the application, because it affects only the current process.
- it also prevents you from extending the solution, e.g. by sharing the data with associated programs
- a database transaction is designed to handle crashes without producing inconsistent data

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you're asking about threading as much as avoiding a race condition.

Not knowing anything about your architecture, one way to avoid such a race is to set a timestamp when each user hits the 'book now' button and pass it as a field in the transaction.  The application server would then sort all the entries in its queue according to the timestamp, as opposed to simply accepting them in the order they arrive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a unique key {room number, date} such that a room can only have one booking per date. Then a client booking becomes an insert of as many rows as there are days in the booking, carried out within a transaction.

Threads really have little to do with it.